# How to filter bounding boxes for yolo train

Tags: deep-learning, yolo

hi i have set of bounding boxes , Before train YOLO algorithm i want to filter the boxes outside some region here is plot i want to keep the green ones they are in almost one column [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the [ask] section, your question has a higher chance of receiving a high quality answer if you included samples of **what you have tried so far** and **exactly what part of your code is not working as expected**.

Answer (score 0):

i think i will use hough transform on centers and take longest line